# This is correct, but it sorts after implementation. Can someone explain to me why this is?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public boolean remove(int x) {
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; (i < size) && (x != array[i]); i++) {
        if (i == size) {
            return false;
        } else {
            size--;
            array[i] = array[size];
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry it's not pretty. I'm typing this on a tablet.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's removing the last item of the array, and slotting it in, in place of the one you deleted.  Isn't that what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking why the array is sorted after `remove` is called then the answer is: it isn't:

```
public class Remove {

    private final int[] array = new int[10];
    private int size = 0;

    public Remove(int... elements) {
        for (int el: elements)
            array[size++] = el;
    }

    public boolean remove(int x) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; (i < size) && (x != array[i]); i++)
            ;
        if (i == size) {
            return false;
        } else {
            size--;
            array[i] = array[size];
            return true;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(array, size));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Remove remove = new Remove(random.ints(8, 1, 1000).toArray());
        System.out.println(remove);
        remove.remove(remove.array[3]);
        System.out.println(remove);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[515, 621, 343, 883, 463, 745, 966, 70]
[515, 621, 343, 70, 463, 745, 966]
```